# es6 import using.mjs suffix fails with MIME error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, module

In the latest chrome browser

```
import foo from '../dist/foo.mjs'
```

fails with

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

But if I copy the file to foo.js

```
import foo from '../dist/foo.js'
```

works!

I am using the mac os x built-in Apache server with localhost paths and the latest chrome.

So somehow es6 imports are sensitive, in the browser, to the preferred node suffix of .mjs.

The import is in a html file with `<script type="module">` rather than a separate module file, but I doubt that is the problem.

Is there a solution to this?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to usa an `.htaccess` file or extend your Apache config file with the following htaccess directive in order for the server to output files with the mjs extension with the correct MIME type:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddType text/javascript js mjs
</IfModule>
```

Of course, `mod_mime` needs to be installed and enabled for this to work.