# How to use ES6 modules on Apache Server?

Tags: javascript, html, apache, mime-types, es6-modules

I am trying to import ES6 modules within a HTML page, but I get the following error:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

This html page is hosted on a Apache server, but to develop my app I use the WebStorm local server and it works.

Here is the code I use to import my modules :

```html
<script type="module" src="js/TextAnalyzer.mjs" application=""></script>
<script type="module" src="js/Overlay.mjs"></script>
<script type="module" src="js/Main.mjs"></script>
```

I've tried both on Chrome and Firefox and I've the same problem.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question was answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995339/es6-import-using-mjs-suffix-fails-with-mime-error). You basically need to create and .HTACCESS file and your project root directory where index.htm or index.html can be accessed, and add this code as its content:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddType text/javascript js mjs
</IfModule>
```

[es6 import using.mjs suffix fails with MIME error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995339/es6-import-using-mjs-suffix-fails-with-mime-error)

Comment: You really shouldn't answer a Stack Overflow question with a link to a duplicate that answers the question. This should be a comment or vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: I wasn't too focused on StackOverflow ethics. Needless to say... I'll do that next time.